# From powershell, why are these two figures different for working set memory used by Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, memory, powershell

I am not that familiar with powershell.

I have 16GB RAM, most of it used by chrome 'cos I have 5 windows open, this one with 30 tabs. And mathematically, 16GB RAM, 16GB for RAM is binary-base a.k.a 16GiB, and adds up to  17179869184 bytes.

From now on i'm just talking in terms of bytes, so decimal.

Total used by chrome according to powershell, according to this command

```
PS C:\Users\user> (Get-Process chrome | Measure-Object WorkingSet -sum).sum
16611123200
```

yet this command shows a different figure

```
PS C:\Users\user> get-process chrome | Group-Object -Property ProcessName | Format-Table Name, @{n='Mem';e={'{0:N0}' -
f (($_.Group|Measure-Object WorkingSet -Sum).Sum )}} -AutoSize
```

> ```
> Name   Mem
> ----   ---
> chrome 16,719,167,488
> ```

Comment: have you tried running them one-**_immediately_**-after-the-other? when i put them both in the same script & run it, the numbers are the same.

Comment: kool! glad to know you got it figured out ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you can post that as an answer! And I will accept it

Comment: while i aint too sure that it's significant enuf to be an Answer ... i will take your advice. see how well the posted Answer satisfies your Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RAM use reports are time-critical.

if you wait any noticeable amount of time, then the amount of RAM used by any given process *may* change significantly. when i run those two lines of code in the same script so that they run *immediately* after each other ... the used RAM is the same.

it appears that your two code snippets were run far enuf apart that the application had noticeably changed the amount of RAM it was using.

Comment: Yeah thanks answers don't need to be "significant"! the explanation in your comment was fine as an answer and concise.. cos site is supposedly for "super users" though even "super users" overlook things often! Good answer too though! Main thing with an answer is it really is the answer, and it is

Comment: @barlop - thank you! i had fun doing this ... [*grin*]

Comment: fortunately I am blessed to not have too much of an ego ;-)